# How to delete specific characters per cell in 1 column, using excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Column A I have this:

## A

1. 0933 456 7377
2. 0948455 9911
3. 0917 330 44 77
4. +63917 234 9999
5. +63 933 727 0415

I want it to be all like this:

## A

1. 09334567377
2. 09484559911
3. 09173304477
4. 09172349990
5. 09337270415

Note: just like the "ctrl+F and replace" function, excep on the first 3 examples i want to delete the spaces. I know that this requires different formulas per cell. Please help me, Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: not actually an excel wiz, tried the ctrl+f & replace and apparently replaced ALL the spaces in the whole sheet. I have 40,000 of this numbers and I was just wondering if I have to edit this manually or not. Thanks by the way for the reply

Comment: yeah, I have so much more data in this sheet! I think replacing the data will work though, its just so time consuming, I mean, I can just copy the whole column in a different sheet and then do the "ctrl+F" thing, but I also want to learn new formulas that might be handy for future use so I tried asking this in this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you put:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="+63",MID(A1,4,15),A1)
```

in your top row and copy down to suit the leading `+63` should be removed. Copy the column with this formula and Paste Special Values over the top so that, with the column selected, Home > Editing > Find & Select, Replace `[space]` with nothing will remove all the spaces.

The result will probably convert to numeric format hence lose the leading `0`s but they may be added back (or in the case of the `+63`s, just added) with a formula such as `="'0"&C1` where C1 should be adjusted to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Give this formula a try (enter into B1 and copy down):

=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+63","")," ",""),"00000000000")